# recognizing dependencies installed as pip install -e

Tags: pycharm

I have some dependencies installed as "pip install -e ." in a conda environment, and PyCharm static Inspectors fail to recognize them, ie they are underlined red as missing even though I can run the code from PyCharm without any import errors. Is there any way I can "help" PyCharm find this dependency?

[image]

Comment: Are the dependencies in a `setup.py` or a conda `environment.yml` file?

Comment: Nope. None of my dependencies are in setup.py or environment.yml, all of them seem to be recognized except this one, I'm guessing the fact that I installed it using `pip install -e .` has something to do with it

Comment: It's a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23335